# How to check if a function's type parameters are statically resolved?

Tags: f#, inline

very simple examples:

1. `let myfun x = x`
   Here in the intellisense it says "x: 'a -> 'a". In the FSI it says "x: 'a -> 'a"
2. `let inline myfun x = x`
   Here in the intellisense it says "x: 'a -> 'a". In the FSI it says "x: 'a -> 'a"  <<<< why not `^a`?
3. `let inline myfun (x: 'b) = x`
   Here in the intellisense it says "x: 'b -> 'b". In the FSI it says "x: 'b -> 'b"
4. `let inline myfun (x: ^b) = x`
   Here in the intellisense it says "x: 'b -> 'b". In the FSI it says "x: ^b -> ^b"  <<<<  different

Since the intellisense never shows `^b`, should I look for `^b` as an indicator of  "statically resolved" in FSI?

Does `inline` guarantee "statically resolved"?

Comment: Yes, it does. That's how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Inline does allow but does not force statically resolved types, that's why in case 2. it remains the same as in case 1.
I think in most cases type inference is smart enough to guess if the type should really be statically resolved, even if you don't specify the `^`.

For example if you change your function body to `sqrt x` in case 3. you'll get

```
> let inline myfun (x: 'b) = sqrt x;;
val inline myfun :  ^b ->  ^a when  ^b : (static member Sqrt :  ^b ->  ^a)
```

I personally always try not to specify types explicitly at first try, then I check if I'm happy with the inference, if I'm not then I try adding inline, but not the hat types.

Why intellisense shows sometimes something different? that's probably a small bug.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that in most cases, putting the '^' doesn't convey any additional information since parameter constraints are only possible on statically resolved type parameters.  The only exception I can think of is the case where you explicitly state that a parameter has a statically resolved type.